# Disable/Block Internet Access from Android Phone

Tags: android

The scenario is, i'm developing an android app that uses the internet. This is a business app. The company will provide android phones to all the employees. Now their requirement is that they don't want employees to use the internet by other means than by their business app, which requires internet access.

In short i need to develop an app that disable the internet (wifi, mobile data etc.) and allow internet only when user is using this App.

Is this possible? How to achieve this? A service that will always be keeping a check on network connectivity?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Im using BroadcastReciever, that detects Connection State and disables the Wifi. How can i detect Connected state of mobile Data, i mean what is the intent filter action to detect mobile data connection and then disable it accordingly, i have tried

`<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>`

Comment: On a side note: gosh, how draconian. It's amazing that some companies operate like this.

Comment: dont think this is possible because while your application is using internet phone user can switch to another application to use internet service

Comment: Well this is what i actually want to manage!Like onPause() i can broadcast an action that will disabled the internet.

Comment: Its possible, but you would have to create your own customized browser.

Comment: Please give some respects to us. Who is "i"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something not suggestable but if you still want to do so,

in onCreate of each activity which uses Internt write this code,

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

and in onPause of that activty write,

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

this is to do for WIFI for GPRS/EDGE/3G you might will have to enable disable Airplane mode same way.

**UPDATE TO DO IT FROM EVERYWHERE**

Take one `SharedPreference` and put one `boolean isAppRunning = true` *every time* you go `in onCreate()` of any of your activity and put `False` *everytime* in each activity's `onDestroy()` method.

Now, **Create one broadcast receiver** that listend to `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED` action and in that receiver's `onReceive()` *check for the SharedPreference value*,

If SP boolean variable is True then Let the WIFI get enabaled and If it's false means your app is not running then toggle the WIFI off again.

Comment: the user can easily enable it!how can this procedure disable internet 4rm evrywhere

Comment: thanks alot!check my update, i did the same, it works, thanks you explain it better